# Best practice to manage API key/secret for AWS based multi-tenancy SaaS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am building a multi-tenancy SaaS with AWS (`Cognito`, `API Gateway`, `Amplify`). I am planning to create `API keys/secrets` for my tenants and trying to figure out the whole process. However, I could find a clear document from AWS.

So I use custom-attribute-based multi-tenancy with Cognito. 2 questions here:

1. What is the best practice to manage API keys/secrets for each tenant? It seems I have to create the key pairs and store them in the database all by myself. I am wondering if there are some services that could help.
2. What is the best practice to verify the keys/secrets? For now, I guess I have to implement the customized authorizer myself to verify the keys.

Answer (score 0):

For the first query, you can simply story API keys/secrets in the AWS SSM - System manager parameter store as secret text and whenever value is required simply call SSM parameter store api to get that value at runtime.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParameter.html

Now for the second point, I believe you are not required to explicitly write logic to verify any API keys/secrets as if a user uses an incorrect key they will get invalid key/secret or unauthorized exception directly from API Gateway and Cognito service calls.